# How do I initialize a lazy variable for a RecyclerView adapter

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have an adapter that takes in a list of items derived from a data class that I need to use for settings the items in the recyclerView.

The adapter looks something like this:

```
class MyAdapter(private var adapterItems: MutableList<MyDataClass>): RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>(){

    override fun OnCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder{
        //Todo
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int): ViewHolder {
       //Todo
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       //Todo
    }

   inner class ViewHolder(
       itemView: View)
   : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
```

Next I have my data class as

```
data class MyDataClass(
val id: Int,
val title: String,
val subTitle: String,
}
```

I am using the following way to create a variable for my adapter in my activity along with other member parameters that I have not mentioned here.

```
    class Activity @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int): RecyclerView(context, attrs, defStyle){

        private val myAdapter: MyAdapter by lazy {
           MyAdapter(mutableListOf()
        }

        init{

            this.adapter = myAdapter
            //Along with layout manager and inflating the recyclerView

            }
    }
```

I have a Fragment class that is responsible for creating the items to be supplied to the adapter and check the working of the recycler view.

Thus doing so, I am facing the following error and have no clue on resolving it:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean
> androids.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()'
> on a null object reference

I have duplicated my code over here for privacy. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is the way I am instantiating the adapter, because the code never reaches the overridden methods

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change your Adapter to a [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter). It will manage updating the list and animate any changed (see also [DiffCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil.ItemCallback) for better update handling).
This way you do not have to rely on instantiating the adapter `by lazy` because you do not have to wait for the displayed items to be created. You can create an `Adapter` with an empty list and set it up with the `RecyclerView`. When the `Fragment` has created the items for the Adapter, you call `adapter.submitList(items)` to give it to the adapter.